# Aerospike: Invalid node exception when writing to single node Aerospike.

Tags: aerospike

I am using Aerospike 3.12.1.1 and Java 4 client.

Aerospike namespace is configured as in memory.  My intention is to write 100 million integers to in memory single-bin namespace using 20 threads parallely, where each thread writes 5 million.

After writing around 75 million records, I am getting following exception at client side.  The cold snippet is given below. Please help.

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-15"     com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$InvalidNode: Error Code -3: Invalid node
at com.aerospike.client.cluster.Cluster.getRandomNode(Cluster.java:717)
at com.aerospike.client.command.Command.getSequenceNode(Command.java:1050)
at com.aerospike.client.command.Command.getNode(Command.java:1020)
at com.aerospike.client.command.SyncCommand.execute(SyncCommand.java:61)
at com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.put(AerospikeClient.java:360)
at Write.run(Write.java:50)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)




import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient;
import com.aerospike.client.Host;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.ClientPolicy;
import com.aerospike.client.Bin;
import com.aerospike.client.Key;
import com.aerospike.client.Record;

import java.io.*;

public class Write implements Runnable{
        int start;
        int count;
        int end;
        private long unixTime;
        private long timeTaken;
        private long totalTimeTaken;
        private long totalRequests;
        private long minLatency;
        private long maxLatency;
        private double avgLatency;
        private FileOutputStream out;

        public  Write(int s, int c){
                this.start = s;
                this.count = c;
                this.end = this.count;
                this.totalTimeTaken = 0;
                this.totalRequests = 0;
                this.minLatency = 1000000;
                this.maxLatency = 0;
                //try{
                //  this.out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
                //}catch(Exception e){
                //}

        }

        public void run(){
                Host[] hosts = new Host[] {
                        new Host("127.0.0.1", 3000),
                };
                AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient(new ClientPolicy(), hosts);
                for(int k=this.start; k<=(this.end); k++){
                        Key key = new Key("mem", null, k);
                        Bin bin1 = new Bin("m", k+count);
                        Bin bin2 = new Bin("n", k+count);
                        Bin bin3 = new Bin("b", k+count);
                        //Bin bin = Bin.asNull("b");
                        unixTime = System.nanoTime();
                        client.put(null, key, bin1, bin2, bin3);
                        timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - unixTime;
                        totalTimeTaken += timeTaken;
                        if(timeTaken < minLatency){
                                minLatency = timeTaken;
                        }
                        if(timeTaken > maxLatency){
                                maxLatency = timeTaken;
                        }
                        totalRequests ++;
                }

                avgLatency = totalTimeTaken / totalRequests;
                System.out.println("TotalReqs:" + totalRequests + " TotalTime:" + totalTimeTaken + " MinLatency:" + ((float)minLatency/1000000.0) + " MaxLatency:" + ((float)maxLatency/1000000.0) + " AvgLatency:" + ((float)avgLatency/1000000.0));


        }
}
```

Comment: What do the logs server side say?

Comment: @Meher Thanks for response. I didn't see any warning or error in server logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the size of the memory defined for this namespace?
Are you using the default hwm (60%) and default stop-write (90%) for this namespace?
What is the RAM available on this node?

Comment: Piyush, Available RAM: 32G, Configured RAM: 24G and operating in default hwm and stop-write configurations.

Comment: So you have more than adequate memory. In other forums, I read that an update was issued to the Java client - 4.0.1 - you may want to try that. See https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/java-client-tendthread-leaves-connections-in-close-wait-state/4207/6

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working now without any issues.